# Error on Building wireshark from source on OS X

Tags: macos, build, wireshark

I am trying to build the wireshark from source ( URL: http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/wireshark/trunk ) on my mac machine but I am getting following error message :

```
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.12.0 and < 3.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: Neither Qt nor GTK+ 2.12.0 or later are available, so Wireshark can't be compiled
```

complete log can be seen at : 
http://hastebin.com/yebayufoxi.vhdl

Please suggest me, how to build wireshark on my mac machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my first suggestion is to install GTK+ and other libraries that Wireshark needs.

The easiest way to install *all* the libraries that Wireshark needs, at least on Snow Leopard and later, run the shell script `macosx-setup.sh` in the top-level directory of the Wireshark source tree.  It will download and install various packages, including GTK+ (and GLib, which both GTK+ and Wireshark itself need).

That script, by default, also installs libraries that Wireshark doesn't *require*, but that allow Wireshark to support additional features (decryption of various types of traffic, Lua as an extension language, geolocation of IP addresses, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Guy Harris for your quick response, I have successfully build the wireshark using `macosx-setup.sh`. One more thing I want to ask, is it recommended to run wireshark using sudo for development purpose.

Comment: I'd recommend installing a Wireshark release, which will set things up so that the `access_bpf` group can open BPF devices and make you a member of that group.  That way, you can run Wireshark, TShark, dumpcap, tcpdump, and other packet capture programs and have them capture traffic without having to run them as root.  As Wireshark's `doc/README.packaging` file says, "WIRESHARK CONTAINS OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE. DO NOT RUN THEM AS ROOT."